# Get content from json data with PHP

Tags: php, json

I have a question. How to get content only from json data.

```
My JSON Data:

array(
(int) 0 => '{"html":"Lorem Ipsum \u2013 Lorem Ipsum \u2013 Lorem Ipsum - Lorem Ipsum \u2013 Lorem Ipsum \u2013 Lorem Ipsum \u2013 Lorem Ipsum"}',
(int) 1 => '{"text":"Lorem Ipsum"}',
(int) 2 => '{"text":"01 June-30 September"}',
(int) 3 => '{"text":"7 nights \/ 8 days"}',
(int) 4 => '{"text":"Lorem Ipsum"}'
);
```

I want to get html and text content only

```
Lorem Ipsum
Lorem Ipsum
01 June-30 September
```

I tried to use `json_decode`.

My Code:

```
foreach($array as $i) {
        $a = json_decode($i);
        echo $a;
}
```

Anyone help me please?

Comment: Use [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). It will return an object. You can get what you need from that.

Comment: Yes. I tried to use `json_decode`. 

`foreach($contents as $i) {
            $a = json_decode($i);
            echo $a;
 }`
_Error message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string_

Comment: use... `echo $a->text;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume your data is stored in a variable called `$a`.

`echo json_decode($a[0], true)['html'];`

will get you the result for the first index of the array. For the other indexes you would use `text` instead of `html`.

Note I've passed `true` for the second argument of [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php), if you prefer to treat the decoded data as an object you can leave that argument off, in which case the code would become

`echo json_decode($a[0])->html;`

Comment: Syntax `functionWhichReturnsArray()[key]` is available only in most recent PHP versions.

Comment: It's been available since php 5.4 which [was released](http://php.net/releases/#5.4.0) on March of 2012.

Comment: 43% of all PHP installations are version 5.3 (January 2015) according to [w3techs.com](http://w3techs.com/technologies/details/pl-php/5/all). In my opinion, the most spread system is Ubuntu 12 LTS, which has PHP 5.3 as stable. Personally, I use 5.6 but answers on SO should be dedicated to what is used most, an oustanding good answer includes current and older code.